# What is what I'm doing called?

Tags: chicken, meat

At restaurants, I know that meats are often cooked by searing or grilling the meat to "mark" it, and then it is put in an oven for some time to be cooked. I also understand that this is done partly for consistency, partly for convenience, and partly for speed.

I've been cooking chicken in a similar manner at home, especially now that it's winter. I season the chicken, then sear both sides in a little bit of oil in a pan (a few minutes per side), and then I put the whole pan in the oven at 425 or so for about 10 minutes.

The chicken always comes out nicely moist and flavorful, and I am happy with the results.

However, when asked what kind of chicken it is, I have no idea what to call it. I'm not really baking it, I'm not frying it, I'm not broiling it, and I'm not roasting it.

...

*Or am I?*

What is this cooking method called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This technique—searing or marking on the grill or stove top, then finishing in an oven—is called [pan roasting](http://www.bonappetit.com/test-kitchen/cooking-tips/article/how-to-pan-roast-chicken-fish-and-meat-like-a-professional-chef).

Answer (score -5):

Searing, often called "sealing," forms a crust on the outside of the meat to seal in the juices while roasting. Some juice will still seep out into the roasting pan, but far less than meat that is not "sealed." "Pan roasting" means it´s cooked on top of the stove in a covered pan; "rossting" is done in the oven.

Comment: Sorry, but almost all of this is incorrect.  Searing does *not* seal in juices; this is [well debunked](http://www.amazingribs.com/tips_and_technique/mythbusting_searing_seals_in_juices.html).   Searing is not called sealing.  Pan roasting does not refer to cooking on top of the stove in a covered pan.